# Github Page won't publish

Tags: github, github-pages

Honestly I don't even know what to write here. I have a simple index.html file in a repository, nothing else. I've tried literally everything from google page 1 to page 2 and nothing makes sense or fixes my problem. I don't even know what the problem is.

It worked a few days ago when I first tried it out. Now, whatever I do, the site simply won't publish...

Comment: What changes have been made since the last publish? Reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help us help you

Comment: I've changed nothing really since I've made a whole new repository (multiple times). I was just trying it out the first time it did it. There really isn't anything else i can tell you since all there is is a fresh repo with an index.html file....